# Query order by custom order

Tags: php, sql

I'm writing a PHP where I call all the States in a list, I'm doing like this.

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM ".TABLE_PREFIX."states WHERE ccode='MX'");
```

The problem is I need to set a custom order, not by ABC, or Numeric, its basically a Custom order, (based on id I think), So I now I can user "Order By", but I don't know which way you set a custom order like "Order by ID (3,5,28,34,13, etc.)

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM ".TABLE_PREFIX."states WHERE ccode='MX' Order by ID '3,5,28,34,13' ");
```

How can I do this?

Comment: This is mysql query, not mysqli

Comment: how? if it says mysqli_query.. i dont get it.

Comment: your database is called mysql, not mysqli

Comment: oh sorry I dont understand quite well the difference between each other.. in my code i just see mysqli is used for querys and stuff.

Answer (score 1):

The function you are looking for is `find_in_set()`:

```
SELECT *
FROM ".TABLE_PREFIX."states
WHERE ccode='MX'
Order by find_in_set(ID, '3,5,28,34,13')
```

This returns the index in the "set", which is what you want for ordering.